# Why is my bot.command function in discord.py not working?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried looking around the internet for answers but I'm not finding anything that fixes my problem:

```
import os
import asyncio

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = "here is my token"

bot = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def length(ctx):
    await ctx.send('your message is {} characters long.'.format(len(ctx.message.content)))
    print("test print")

bot.run(token)
```

The `length` function does not work at all, and its not printing test print in the console.

Does anyone know what the problem is? there are a few other `bot.xxx` functions in there that works.

Comment: dan1st formatted your code. Can you run it again and edit your question with error. You might had some syntax error. From first glance there doesn't seem anything wrong with it. Just some unnecessary lines but else it looks good. Need an error traceback.

Comment: Same is with my code

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you have double bot.
Your should only have `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`

Comment: Since the 1st assigned value never gets used, and it's immediately over written by the second, why would removing it fix the issue? If the 1st assignment itself causes an error, please explain why/how.

Comment: Because you can't run bot and client in the same time although is overwritten, it's created.